# Different methods are making use of the same other methods. How to know which method is currently using one of these other methods?

Tags: c#, reflection, log4net

I have a Windows Service, which runs 4 different methods periodically.
I am using log4net to log these methods.

**The 4 different methods use some of the same other methods to do their job.**

**My problem is that in the logging I need to know which of the 4 methods is actually using one of the other methods at a given time.**

One solution to this problem is to equip the other methods, which the methods are using, with an extra parameter, telling which method is using the other method at a given time.

But I was just wondering if there is a another way to accomplish this? Being able to log which of my 4 methods are using the other method at a given time?

It seems a little clumsy to equip all my methods with this extra parameter in order to know which of my methods originated the call to the outside method.

The scenario is also a little more complex, because sometimes the workflow is:

**My Windows Service method calls another method.
This other method then calls another method, which again call another method, etc.
I need to be able to track down which of my Windows Service methods originated the calls.**

**So the task is to implement a mechanism so I can know which of my Windows Service methods originated the method calls.**

Any idea? Apart from the obvious one: equiping all the methods with an extra parameter to pass on which of my Windows Service methods that originated the call?

Comment: Are those 4 processes instances of the same application or are they totally different (with different names, etc.?)

Comment: Hi Martin, its a Windows Service, which periodically runs 4 different methods (processes), these methods (processes) sometimes calls the same outside methods, which call other outside methods. For logging I need to know which of my processes started the outside method calls.

Comment: What do you mean with: "outside method"?

Comment: If you say "methods (processes)", what do you mean? A method? Or a process? Those are two different things...

Comment: Ah sorry Martin, I didn't know that terminology. Well it's just a method, which calls some other outside methods, which again call other outside methods. So I need to know which method started the calls. Perhaps I do need to equip my methods with an extra parameter to know this? Outside method is just another method.

Comment: Terminology is very important to communicatie with other programmers. We alle speak english but we also have to speak the same technical language. Did you already try my answer with Assembly.GetEntryAssembly?

Comment: Yes I am sorry about my ignorance. I have probably given you a wrong impression of the scenario. I have now edited my question. I haven't tried Assembly.GetEntryAssembly, there was another answered who suggested StackTrace below, and I suspect that can give me what I was looking for.

Comment: So... there are not different processes?

Comment: I updated my answer. I think this is more "clean" that any stracktrace or entry assembly or what so ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have modified the question, I modifed the answer:

The most clean way is to create a context:

```
public class Context: IDisposable
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static private Context _Current;

    static public Context Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _Current;
        }
    }

    private readonly Context _Previous;

    public Context(string id)
    {
        ID = id;
        _Previous = _Current;
        _Current = this;
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Current = _Previous;
    }
}
```

You can use this Context to `mark` your method by creating a context. This context is retrievable at another part in your code:

```
static void MethodA()
{
    using (new Context("A"))
    {
        SharedMethod();
    }
}

static void MethodB()
{
    using (new Context("B"))
    {
        SharedMethod();
    }
}

static void SharedMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Context.Current.ID);
}
```

In this example I only showed 2 different methods calling a shared method, but I think you can translate this into four.

Comment: Hi Martin thank you for your offer for a solution. But in my scenario my shared methods call other shared methods, is your solution working in that scenario? I like most the StackTrace solution which seems very simple and easily applicable:                                             StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
string initiatingMethod = stackFrames[2].GetMethod().Name;

Comment: @Rune: The method I offered is used by .NET itself for regulating transactions. Everthing which is called inside the `new Context` (and it does not matter how many calls deep a method is) can use the `Context.Current`. So yes, it does apply. The Stackframe is also applicable, but for me it feels more like a hack than "clean" programming.

Comment: Ok thank you Martin :) I will also consider your solution when I am implementing my project.

Comment: I am currently prone to use your solution Martin, the thing is that my originating methods might hit the other methods at different levels of depth, and in that case StackTrace will give me different results dependent upon the level of depth. Whereas with your solution that's not a concern :)

Comment: @Rune: Well, glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you cannot modify the code of those four processes (if you could then it's simple matter of putting logging statements in code of those for processes), you could use `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` class in the outside methods. Then using GetFrames method on that stack trace object will give you the call stack for that point in code.

```
StackTrace t = new StackTrace();
StackFrame[] stackFrames = t.GetFrames();
```

For an example [check this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-callstack/).

Comment: Hi bytefire, your suggestion seems interesting. That might actually give me what I am looking for. I must check it out in the next days. Thank you so far. I'll be back :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this information always, your best bet is to do what you already suggested.
Now, if you just want to debug a problem and need to know `who called who when`, then you can have that info easily with Process Explorer:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/04/02/getting-better-stack-traces-in-process-monitor-process-explorer.aspx